# Undocumented Tennis Shots

Tags: technique, tennis, training, strategy

I referred [Tennis shots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_shots) but didn’t see about `looper`  and `short angles`. These two shots are helping a beginner like me to win some games. So, what are such gems like shots that are not documented in the above mentioned article?

**REFERENCES**

1. Short Angles:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xb_Rch1MOUQ
2. Looper:-       https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NH5BskSIK3Q
3. Reply Looper:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRaH7lJtBSU
4. Moon Ball on the Rise - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tilMGez0xos
5. Hit on the Rise - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5RzALUWp88

**More**

1. Buggy Whip - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bk3iuGZtwm8
2. [Two Handed Forehand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xNOtBplusU&index=1&list=PL5Hnmol1rQ44W6wYnZx6ZZawMSjhEArcd)
3. [Forehand Lag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wicWX3dH0cU&index=9&list=PL5Hnmol1rQ44W6wYnZx6ZZawMSjhEArcd)
4. Forehand Topspin https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4suR2knOitY
5. Reverse Dropshot - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTnlgp55VkI

Comment: More. Nadal's Buggy Whip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nM4thCEf7fI... Murray's Buggy whip - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfaZQT_DDR4

Comment: Open Stance Forehand - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLIa-dFTtKQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the article you referenced was merely trying to explain all the different shot types that can be hit without getting into specifics or variations on each shot. In the list of shots you mentioned, they can all fall under the shots mentioned in that article.

1. Short Angles: any kind of shot really can have a "short angle" to it, depending on how you hit it
2. Looper: this is really just a variation on a lob
3. Reply Looper: this is just a certain type of "on the rise" timing of a ground stroke (forehand or backhand)
4. Moon Ball on the Rise: Again, just a certain type of ground stroke with specific take-back preparation and specific timing (forehand or backhand)
5. Hit on the Rise: This is just a backhand or forehand being hit sooner and more up in the court (usually) than a normal ground stroke that you let start falling first.

There are a lot of what you might call "ad-hoc" or "improvisational" type shots in the game of tennis and you might hit them without even knowing what they're called, but in the end, it all boils down to the main types of shots you can hit - forehand, backhand, serve, volley, overhead smash and lob. For example - a drop volley and a half volley are both volley type shots, even though they have a little bit more specific names.